# Couterexample to Littlewood-Paley theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, unbounded-operators, littlewood-paley-theory

Let $d\geq 2$ and let $P_j$ be the Fourier multiplier defined on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ by $\widehat{P_kf}(\xi)=\mathbf{1}_{2^k<|\xi|\leq2^{k+1}} \hat f(\xi)$, for any $k \ge 0$. It has been proven by Fefferman that:

> **Theorem.** For any $1<p<\infty$ such that $p\neq 2$, $P_k$ is not continuous from $L^p$ to $L^p$.

Let us fix such a $p\neq 2$.

> **Question.** Prove that there is no constant $C>0$ such that for any $f \in ^p$
>   $$\left\|\left(\sum_{k \geq 0} |P_kf|^2\right)^{1/2}\right\|_{L^p} \leq C\|f\|_{L^p}.$$

The basic idea should be to use the theorem to produce counterexamples. More precisely, for any $N>0$ we can pick a $f_N \in L^p$ such that for all $k$ there holds $\|P_kf_N\|_{L^p} >N \|f_N\|_{L^p}$ (this should be true, at least for any $k$ we can pick such a sequence), but then how can I deduce something on $\left\|\left(\sum_{k \geq 0} |P_kf_N|^2\right)^{1/2}\right\|_{L^p}$?

Comment: Do you want a direct answer or would you admit an answer using something like Feffermann's ball multiplier theorem?

Comment: I'm sorry my question is not clearly phrased, what you provided is fine!

Comment: Perfect! You can use the ball theorem to see that $P_k$ is unbounded. I do not know if there are "simpler" proofs.

Comment: If there is a simpler proof that would be nice! Yet, this yields a proof!

Comment: Why we can pick a $f_N\in L^p$ such that for all $k$ there holds $ \lVert P_k f_N\rVert _{L^p}>N\lVert f_N\rVert_{L^p}$?Can you give me some reference?@J.Mayol

Comment: @Mr.xue this is just the Fefferman theorem stated at the begining of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix some $k$ and assume that there is a sequence such that $\| P_k(f_N) \|_p \geq N \| f_N \|_p$. Normalizing $f_N$ you can assume that they all live in the unit ball. But, by the closed graph theorem, there is a $f$ with $\| f \|_p = 1$ such that $\| P_k f \|_p = \infty$. But clearly
$$
  |g_{k_0}| \leq \Big(\sum_k |g_k|^2\Big)^\frac12 \in L^p
$$
implies that all the summands $g_k$ are in $L^p$. Taking $g_k = P_k f$ gives a contradiction.